# Cross product angle formula

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product

Say there are two vectors $A$ and $B$ in $3D$.

to get the angle between the cross product of those two vectors, you use

$$||A\times B|| = ||A||\;||B||\sin(\theta). $$

right?

Is this equation equivalent to $||A\times B|| = AB$(dot product of $AB$) * sin(theta)?

Comment: no it's not ! $A\cdot B\neq \|A\|\|B\|$ in general.

Answer (score 1):

No to both questions.

1. It's usually easier to use the *dot product* $A\cdot B = |A|\,|B|\,\cos\theta$.
2. It is only equivalent if either $\sin\theta=0$ or $A\cdot B=|A|\,|B|$ which happens when $\cos\theta=1$. 
   (So, almost never..)

Comment: so you are saying ||AxB|| = ||A||*||B||*sin(theta). is wrong? Isn't this a proven formula?

Comment: No, this one I didn't say:) The formula is good, and you can actually use it to get $\theta$. But it is usually easier to use the dot product.

Comment: Ohhhh. Ok. Misunderstood you there. Thx for the answer!

Comment: No, they are saying that the formula $\|A\times B\|=\left|\,A\cdot B\,\right|\sin(\theta)$ is false, in general.

Comment: It's simply because, by coordinates, the dot product is easier to express.

Comment: @robjohn in general as in, any dimensions outside of 3D right? Since cross product is only defined in 3D.

Comment: No, "in general" as in "for most values of $\theta$".

Comment: No, "in general", for all $\theta$ the formula you asked is false, except for $\theta=k\pi$ whence your formula happens to be valid.